# Select distinct

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, nodes

I need some help to build a query with Views module.
I have a node which is related to two vocabulary of taxonomy which are not related between them.

A work is represented by a node, and each work has an artist(X,Y,Z) and a type of artist(masters, painters...) that define the artist. This has been designed in this way because each artist can belong to many types of artist
 When I create a new work, I choose an artist and for this artist that I chose, I choose it type of artist. How can I get in a view each artist one time of each type of artist?
for instance : the node table in the db:

work_name | artist_name | type_of_artist
work_name1| artist_name1| masters
work_name2| artist_name1| masters
work_name3| artist_name2| masters
work_name4| artist_name1| painters
work_name5| artist_name1| painters
work_name6| artist_name3| painters

How can i get, if i choose masters the artist_name1 one time and artist_name2 one time
and when i choose painters, i get artist_name1 one time and artist_name3 ?

Thank you very much.
I sorry for my english i'm french.

Comment: How are you representing artists?  Are they data in a field?  Taxonomy terms?  Users?  Nodes?

Comment: By taxonomy terms